# filter overlapping timetable

Tags: sql

I have a booking table where it store the booked date and time:

| id | date | starttime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21/12/2022 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
| 2 | 21/12/2022 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |

How can I filter using date time like :

```
9:30:00 to 11:30:00 is overlap  
10:45:00 to 11:45:00 is overlap
10:00:00 to 14:00:00 is overlap
12:00:00 to 13:00:00 is not overlap
```

Comment: Are the time ranges contained in a table?

Comment: yes it is in a  table

Comment: Check if answer below can help with your problem.

Comment: Your example start and end date is overlapped? The booking table is where I store all the booked date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your time ranges are contained in a table like this:

| startRange | endRange |
| --- | --- |
| 9:30:00 | 11:30:00 |
| 10:45:00 | 11:45:00 |
| 10:00:00 | 14:00:00 |
| 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 |

You can select all ranges which satisfy either one of these two conditions:

- "*startRange*" is later than "*endTime*"
- "*endRange*" is earlier than "*startRange*"

This can be translated into an anti-join, namely:

- you join rows on `startRange < endTime` and `endRange > startRange`
- then get every ranges record without matches (`WHERE bookings.<any_field> IS NULL`)

```
SELECT ranges.* 
FROM      ranges
LEFT JOIN bookings
       ON ranges.startRange < bookings.endTime
      AND ranges.endRange > startRange
WHERE bookings.id IS NULL
```

This will return any range non overlapping with any bookings for the specific day.

If instead you want to assign 'overlap', 'not-overlap' as strings in a separate field, query changes just slightly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ranges.*, 
                CASE WHEN bookings.id IS NULL 
                     THEN 'not-overlap'
                     ELSE 'overlap' 
                END AS overlap_or_not
FROM      ranges
LEFT JOIN bookings
       ON ranges.startRange < bookings.endTime
      AND ranges.endRange > startRange
```

Comment: No, the time cannot overlap, your example time is overlap, and your example is without date.

Comment: Test both queries, or update your post to show all your input tables and expected output.